# Spring Data mapping doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table **option** with two foreign keys and many-to-one associations (to tables **checkpoint** and **setting**): [db schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niwyB.png).

From JPA side I have 2 bidirectional associations: with *Cascade.ALL* and *FetchType.EAGER* on the one side and *Cascade.REMOVE* on the second side. Here is corresponding JPA mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "checkpoint")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Checkpoint {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private long location;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checkpoint",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<RewardOption> rewardOptions = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "setting")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RewardSetting {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "base_line")
  private long baseLine;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rewardSetting",
        cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
        orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<RewardOption> rewardOptions = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "option")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RewardOption {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private long weight;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "setting_id")
  private RewardSetting rewardSetting;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "checkpoint_id")
  private Checkpoint checkpoint;
}
```

Also I'm using Spring Data for entity manipulations. To me it seemed as working example, but on practice when I perform:

```
...
rewardSettingRepository.delete(rewardSetting);
```

Or:

```
...
rewardSettingRepository.delete(id);
```

I got JPA tries to remove a row from **setting** table *BEFORE* corresponding rows from a **option** table.

Does anyone have some ideas why it behaves this way?
Why this mapping leads to this behaviour?
How to do this right way?

The full stack trace is:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.delete(Unknown Source)
>       at com.github.star67.hibernatefetchcascade.HibernateFetchCascadeApplication.testSettingDelete(HibernateFetchCascadeApplication.java:41)
>       at com.github.star67.hibernatefetchcascade.HibernateFetchCascadeApplication.main(HibernateFetchCascadeApplication.java:36)
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3261)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3498)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:98)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>       ... 18 more
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demo`.`option`, CONSTRAINT `FKdhs5wopt13o6b9gl4wydr0l9o` FOREIGN KEY (`setting_id`) REFERENCES `setting` (`id`))
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:115)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1116)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1066)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1396)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1051)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>       ... 37 more

Also, after playing around I found some strange things, that I cannot explain:

1. Adding *@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)* for **Checkpoint** in the class **RewardOption** fixes the problem, but how fetch type influences cascade?
2. Changing *cascade = CascadeType.ALL* to *cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE* in the class **Checkpoint** fixes the problem but I need ability to save cascade...

If anyone could throw some light on these "fixes" it would be great.

**[Here is the code to play around](https://github.com/star67/demo/tree/master)**

Comment: What happens if you set CascadeType.ALLinstead of CascadeType.REMOVE?

Comment: Enable SQL logging, and see which SQL queries are actually executed, and in which order. My guess is that the setting you're trying to delete doesn't have the actual list of options referencing it in its list of options.

Comment: @RenéWinkler do you mean in the class **RewardSetting**? It's the same.
However changing cascade to REMOVE in the class **Checkpoint** makes it working, however I need the ability to save cascade...

Comment: @JBNizet do you have any ideas why options list is null?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, you need to [synchronize both end of the bidirectional association](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/).

That means, prior to calling delete, you need to make sure you disassociate the parent from al child entities.

Comment: Thanks, Vlad, but could you please explain WHY it warns me that removed entity is going to be re-saved via another Cascade in another association of this entity?

Comment: Because it is still reference there. You have to make sure you clear all traces from all 3 sides. The other parent side might still reference some  join entity entries pointing to the deleting entity.